# Filter pyodbc recordset comparing with threshold list of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a requirement where I need to filter the output from pyodbc based on the predefined list of object.

Data from pyodbc.

```
 question  | Response | id
 ___________________________
 question1 | 6        |  200
 question2 | 3        |  23
 question3 | yes      |  44
 question4 | no       |  5000
 question5 | 7        |  5
```

The object defined to hold criteria is

```
class GroupFilter(object):
    def __init__(self,group,question_filters):
        self.group=group               
        self.question_filters=question_filters
```

```
class QuestionFilter(object):
    def __init__(self,question,threshold,operator):
        self.question=question               
        self.threshold=threshold
        self.operator=operator
```

Filter criteria is defined like

```
        g1q1=QuestionFilter("question1",5,">")
        g1q3=QuestionFilter("question3","yes","=")
        g1q5=QuestionFilter("question5","8",">=")
        g1ql=[g1q1,g1q3,g1q5]

        g2q1=QuestionFilter("question1",6,">")
        g2q3=QuestionFilter("question3","no","=")
        g2q5=QuestionFilter("question5","8","<")
        g2ql=[g2q1,g2q3,g2q5]


        gf=[]

        gf.append(GroupFilter("groupA",g1ql))
        gf.append(GroupFilter("groupB",g2ql))
```

Now, I would like to get a filtered list from data from pyodbc for each group in list of "gf"  that satisfies the criteria specified in QuestionFilter Object for each group.

Output for Group A should be

```
question  | Response | id
 ___________________________
 question1 | 6        |  200
 question3 | yes      |  44
```

Output for GroupB should be

```
     question  | Response | id
     ___________________________
     question4 | no       |  5000
     question5 | 7        |  5
```

I appreciate your help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by looping through group filter and then through question filter and comparing the data with the resultset from data. If it returns a result, i extend a main list.

The final list is the filtered resultset.